# Variable Doesn't Work In Array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, variables

I am trying to print this word press query, but the variable doesn't work in that array (these numbers are just example). It will just take first number 53 and not the other numbers.

```
$catfeaturenumbers = '53,57,4294,71';
$categoryfeatured = array($catfeaturenumbers);
$featured = array(
'post__in' => $categoryfeatured
);
```

Comment: That does not create the array you think it does. Do `print_r($categoryfeatured);` to see the array structure and after that you probably want to look at `explode()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like below:-

```
<?php

$catfeaturenumbers = '53,57,4294,71';

// create an array through explode

$categoryfeatured = explode(',',$catfeaturenumbers);

echo "<pre/>";print_r($categoryfeatured); // print array to check
$featured = array(
 'post__in' => $categoryfeatured
);
```

Note:- if you want to use your original string into an `IN QUERY`(example `SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE id IN (your original string data)`) then do like below:-

```
$categoryfeatured = "'".implode("','",explode(',',$catfeaturenumbers))."'";

echo  $categoryfeatured;
```

Both code Output link:-https://eval.in/662140

Comment: It worked ! thank you very much, even if I don't understand logic behind it.

Comment: It's simple, you need to pass an array to your query, you have string . so you have to convert it to array first.So `explode()` did that work.